# Illegal string offset when accessing array value

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array called `$shops`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [open] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [day] => Monday
                            [start] => 09:00:00
                            [end] => 17:00:00
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [day] => Tuesday
                            [start] => 09:00:00
                            [end] => 17:00:00
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [day] => Thursday
                            [start] => 09:00:00
                            [end] => 17:00:00
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

When I loop through it similar to the following I get `Illegal string offset 'day'`

```
foreach($shops as $shop)
{
    foreach($shop['open'] as $open)
    {
        print_r($open);
        echo $open['day'];
    }
}
```

The `print_r($open)` appears correct:

```
Array
(
    [day] => Monday
    [start] => 09:00:00
    [end] => 17:00:00
)
```

I must be doing something stupid. What's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried [php array iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) . Foreach loops over **all the keys** regardless of levels

Comment: [Works](https://3v4l.org/PluGl) for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have write these code in details with check all iteration. In second loop first iteration has no `day index` and it's value is `10`. you can check [output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a74d998855633c413b7694b3096f1d2378fb40bb)

```
$count=0;
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($shops as $shop) {
    print_r($shop);
    echo "first\n";
    foreach($shop as $open)
    {
        echo "second\n";
        print_r($open);
        if(isset($open[0]))
        {
            foreach ($open as  $value) {
                print_r($value['day']);
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Also you can Check this code. and output of this code is [Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6849b91981e5ae246c73e7724d01b723ceefd531) . further you can split this in `nested foreach loop`

```
<?php

$shops = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'id' => 10,
            'open' => Array
                (
                    0 => Array
                        (
                            'day' => 'Monday',
                            'start' => '09:00:00',
                            'end' => '17:00:00',
                        ),

                    1 => Array
                        (
                            'day' => 'Tuesday',
                            'start' => '09:00:00',
                            'end' => '17:00:00',
                        ),

                    2 => Array
                        (
                            'day' => 'Thursday',
                            'start' => '09:00:00',
                            'end' => '17:00:00',
                        ),
                )
        )
);


foreach ($shops[0]['open'] as $open) {
    print_r($open['day']);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incoming stupidity :/ When I was looping over the array I found the last element didn't have day, start or end - just active. Hence why the error was thrown. I just missed it because the array was big and it threw the error without displaying any previous values so I assumed it was breaking on the first element.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [open] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [day] => Monday
                            [start] => 09:00:00
                            [end] => 17:00:00
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [day] => Tuesday
                            [start] => 09:00:00
                            [end] => 17:00:00
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [day] => Thursday
                            [start] => 09:00:00
                            [end] => 17:00:00
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [active] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
)
```